# converting java EE project into EJB project

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-mq, rad

Currently i am doing the project in RAD i.e. dynamic web project but now there is a requirement that we need to use websphere MQ for queuing the services . so in order to do queue i found to create EJB project . so i can convert dynamic web project into EJB project ?
is there any ways to add facets to current project ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you *need* an EJB project in order to use JMS, but regardless - no, you can't change a dynamic Web project into an EJB project using RAD. Once the Dynamic Web Project facet (and its accompanying facets) is installed, you cannot remove it. You can add other facets, but you can't add the EJB facets. You will have to create a brand new RAD project and copy the code over.

Comment: I am asked to create message driven bean and do JAXB conversations . so i thought of EJB Project . its right??

Comment: Now it sounds differently. If you want to have a Message Driven Bean which reacts upon incoming messages - than you need an EJB container / project.  
I guess that Isaac was referring to the fact that you don't need the EJB's to **use** JMS like **sending** messages. Message can be sent from many Java EE components and from places which are not even written / run by Java.